# for loop in function node causes crash in Node-RED application on IBM Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant, node-red

I'm currently using Node-RED as a cloud-foundry-application on IBM Bluemix. So i'm using the flow editor of Node-RED which is running on a Google Chrome Browser. In my flow, i've a function-node and everytime this one is executed, the app crashes and i've to restart it.

Here is the code of the function-node:

```
var id_array = context.get('id_array')||[];
var id_index = context.get('id_index')||0;
var first_time_execution = context.get('first_time_execution')||true;
var i;
var sensor_id = msg.payload.sensor_data.sensor_id;

if(first_time_execution){
    id_array[0] = undefined; 
    first_time_execution = false;
    context.set('first_time_execution', first_time_execution);
}

/*for(i = 0; (id_array[i] === undefined) || (i > 256); i++){
    if(sensor_id == id_array[i]){
        msg.payload.array_index = i;

        context.set('id_array', id_array);
        context.set('id_index', id_index);

       return msg;
    }
}*/

id_array[id_index] = sensor_id;
msg.payload.array_index = id_index;

if(id_index > 256){
    id_index = 0;
}else{
    id_index++;
}

context.set('id_array', id_array);
context.set('id_index', id_index);

return msg;
```

I've located the problem in the for loop between the /* */, because without this section, the app doesn't crash.

What i want to do is: I get a msg object with sensor data from a gateway. Connected to this gateway are several sensors, which have an ID and are sending measurement data to the gateway. To distinguish and store those data, i want to register the ID of every sensor and store it in the conxtext of the node. In the for loop i'm checking if the ID has already been registered.

If anyone knows what could cause this crash, i would be very thankfull.

P.S. I don't know if this is important, but the credential, settings and the flow itself are stored in a cloudantDB.

Comment: You might want to look at global/flow instead of context.  Regardless, it would be good to include your log output.  Run `bx cf logs <appname>` to tail the logs, reproduce the crash, see if anything relevant in there.  Or you could subject yourself to the UI and look in the log there.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: My gut tells me setting the context inside a loop is not going to be optimal.  It's usually possible to reference/copy the value from context, make local changes and then put it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a  javascript for loop the condition is in essence a while and not an until so for your condition

```
(id_array[i] === undefined) || (i > 256)
```

The left side of the or is true when the field is undefined. The right side is true when the iteration has gone beyond 256. Which means that you will be accessing id_array[257] and beyond, and will get an unaccessible memory exception, which unless caught will crash your application.